# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception due to Could not download artifact when building RxJava

Tags: gradle, rx-java

What might be the reason for the build of RxJava project failing with the following exception?

```
jacek:~/oss/RxJava
$ ./gradlew build -x test
...
:rxjava-contrib:rxjava-android:compileJava
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/xerces/xmlParserAPIs/2.6.2/xmlParserAPIs-2.6.2.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/xerces/xmlParserAPIs/2.6.2/xmlParserAPIs-2.6.2.jar

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':rxjava-contrib:rxjava-android:provided'.
> Could not download artifact 'org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:2.2.1@jar'
   > Artifact 'org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:2.2.1@jar' not found.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 48.057 secs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you see the error, it's most likely that your `~/.m2/repository` contains partially-resolved dependency (in this case, it's `org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:2.2.1@jar`):

```
$ ls ~/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-error-diagnostics/2.2.1/
_maven.repositories                     maven-error-diagnostics-2.2.1.pom       maven-error-diagnostics-2.2.1.pom.sha1
```

Just remove the directory of the dependency from the `~/.m2/repository`...

```
$ rm -rf ~/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-error-diagnostics/2.2.1/
```

...and re-run the build. It should now build fine.

```
jacek:~/oss/RxJava
$ ./gradlew build -x test
...
:rxjava-contrib:rxjava-swing:build

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1 mins 48.046 secs
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your local maven cache is corrupted.
Clean it as below:

```
rm -rf ~/.m2
```